# Leer/escribir arrays de char en ficheros binarios

Tags: c, string, archivo

Estoy intentando guardar binariamente strings a partir de arrays estáticos de caracteres para posteriormente imprimirlos. La cuestión es que, pese a a que les asigno el valor de manera estática (con lo que al crearlos, se deberían crear con el `\0` al final, por lo que no debería ponerlo yo a mano). El mayor problema es que estos arrays forman parte de una estructura, por lo que les he dado un valor máximo en la declaración de la misma y posteriormente asignar valores. Dicha estructura parece guardarse correctamente, pero al leer los arrays, no se imprimen correctamente. He aquí el código:

La estructura:

```
typedef struct
{
    char P [250];
    char R1 [250] ;
    char R2 [250] ;
    char R3[250]  ;

} t_p_r;
```

La asignación de valores a sus arrays y el intento de impresión de los mismos:

```
arrPreg =(t_p_r*)malloc(sizeof(t_p_r));

        t_p_r preg;

        strcpy(preg.P,"hola");
        strcpy(preg.R1,"1");
        strcpy(preg.R2, "2");
        strcpy(preg.R3 ,"3");

        arrPreg[0] = preg;
        guardarPR(arrPreg,1);

        pS = (t_p_r*)malloc(sizeof(t_p_r));
        size = leerPR(pS);


        for(int i=0; i<strlen(pS[0].P);i++)
        {
            printf("%c\n", pS[0].P[i] );
        }
```

Los métodos para lectura/escritura:

```
void guardarPR(t_p_r P[], int numP)
{
  FILE* fichero = fopen("PR.dat", "wb");  
  fputc(numP, fichero);
  fwrite(&P, sizeof( t_p_r), numP, fichero);
  fclose(fichero);
}

int leerPR(t_p_r* PL)
{
    int numElem;

  FILE* fichero = fopen("PR.dat", "rb");

  numElem = fgetc(fichero);
  PL= (t_p_r*) malloc((numElem) * sizeof(t_p_r));
  fread(&PL, sizeof(t_p_r) , numElem, fichero);
  fclose(fichero);

  return numElem;
}
```

EDIT

Así mismo, he hecho otra prueba, esta vez guardando las estructuras individualmente. Aunque da un mejor resultado, sigue sin funcionar:

```
    guardarSingular(preg);
    t_p_r preg2;
    leerSingular(&preg2);
        printf(" %s\n", preg2.P);
        printf(" %s\n", preg2.R1);
        printf(" %s\n", preg2.R2);
        printf(" %s\n", preg2.R3);


void guardarSingular(t_p_r PG)
{
  FILE* fichero = fopen("PR.dat", "wb"); 
  fputc(1, fichero);
  fwrite(&PG, sizeof(t_p_r), 1, fichero);
  fclose(fichero);
}

void leerSingular(t_p_r* PL)
{
  FILE* fichero = fopen("PR.dat", "rb");
  fread(PL, sizeof(t_p_r) , 1, fichero);
  fclose(fichero);
}
```

Al parecer, en vistas al resultado, las estructuras parecen guardarse bien, pero a la hora de leerlas y querer mostrarlas, muestran caracteres extraños distintos a los introducidos al inicio. ¿Cómo puedo almacenar esta estructura en un fichero binario para poder recuperar sus strings tal y como los guardé?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Dicha estructura parece guardarse correctamente

Pues yo diría que no:

```
void guardarPR(t_p_r P[], int numP)
//                   ^^^ P es un puntero
{
  FILE* fichero = fopen("PR.dat", "wb");  
  fputc(numP, fichero);
  fwrite(&P, sizeof( t_p_r), numP, fichero);
  //     ^^ En el fichero guardas la referencia al puntero
  fclose(fichero);
}
```

`fwrite` te pide un puntero a la información a guardar... y tu le estás pasando la referencia a un puntero... es decir, un puntero doble...

Prueba a pasarle el puntero directamente:

```
void guardarPR(t_p_r P[], int numP)
{
  FILE* fichero = fopen("PR.dat", "wb");  
  fputc(numP, fichero);
  fwrite(P, sizeof( t_p_r), numP, fichero); // <<--- Linea modificada
  fclose(fichero);
}
```

Aunque el código será más legible si cambias la firma de la función:

```
void guardarPR(t_p_r *P, int numP)
```

---

Y ahora vamos a revisar la lectura:

```
int leerPR(t_p_r* PL)
{
  int numElem;
  FILE* fichero = fopen("PR.dat", "rb");
  numElem = fgetc(fichero);
  PL= (t_p_r*) malloc((numElem) * sizeof(t_p_r)); // <<--- cambio local
  fread(&PL, sizeof(t_p_r) , numElem, fichero);
  fclose(fichero);
  return numElem;
}
```

Si tu tienes un código tal que:

```
void func (int var)
{ var = 10; }

int main ()
{
  int v;
  func (v);
  printf ("%d\n",v);
}
```

¿que valor imprime?

La respuesta correcta es un numero indeterminado y es facil ver que la asignación que se hace en `func` es local... con el valor de los punteros pasa exactamente lo mismo... los punteros se usan para modificar una memoria común... no para usar una memoria diferente... si quieres ese efecto debes usar punteros dobles:

```
int leerPR(t_p_r** PL)
{
  int numElem;
  FILE* fichero = fopen("PR.dat", "rb");
  numElem = fgetc(fichero);
  *PL= (t_p_r*) malloc((numElem) * sizeof(t_p_r));
  fread(*PL, sizeof(t_p_r) , numElem, fichero);
  fclose(fichero);
  return numElem;
}
```

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar pero el resultado que me da es el mismo

Comment: Aplicando ambas modificaciones ha funcionado, ¡Muchas gracias!